# Objective-C - Swift bridge causes: "String" file not found error

Tags: swift, objectify, file-not-found, bridging-header

I am noob to macOS, and never had done anything on it, now I am forced to work on it for my thesis (I have 10 more days to finish it)
I have to connect a foreign, CocoaPods based objc project's test function with my python codes, and Swift seemed to be the easiest option for calling both objc and python (of course, I have tried several other methods too, which I will list below). The Python way worked, but after importing the necessary objc header to the objc-swift bridge I received the following error:

> failed to emit precompiled header `<bridging header path>`
> `<file path that includes string>` 'string' file not found

It is important, that it works finely without: importing to the bridging header something that is imports a C++ header!

Here is what I've tried to do before:

- I have checked that all relevant file's extensions are changed from '.m' to '.mm'
- I have added `libcc.tbd` under `Build Phases/Link Binary With Libraries`
- Changed `Build Settings/User-Defined/CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY` to `libcc`.
- Tried out all possibilities under `Build settings/Apple Clang - Language - C++/C++ Language Dialect`.

I am sure, that I have tried out even more obscure possibilities, but I have been working on this for 2 weeks and may have forgot some of them.

I have also tried different approaches to solve the python - ObjectiveC interaction:

1. Calling terminal from ObjectiveC with `NSTask`: 'launchPath' is unavailable: not available on iOS        AND         'launch' is unavailable: not available on iOS
2. Calling objectiveC test function from terminal with xcodebuild: The Test Target is dependent on a Host Application Target, and the Host Application's Library Search Path params point to a .app file. It builds in Xcode, but does not in xcodebuild (I don't know the science behind it).

Comment: Can you show what the bridging header you're trying to use looks like? Are you able to reproduce the problems in a brand new Xcode project, or just the project you're working on? Concrete details for someone else to reproduce the issue will help significantly to understand what you're seeing.

Comment: The briding header is quite simple:
`#ifndef LetSeeKeyPointProcessor-Bridging-Header.h
    
#define LetSeeKeyPointProcessor-Bridging-Header.h

#import "QATest.h"

#endif /* LetSeeKeyPointProcessor-Bridging-Header.h */`    
I will try to reproduce it from scratch (I am really bad with Mac, I hope I can do it)

Comment: why do you need Objective C at all? why not use pure Swift?

Comment: A would like to use it, but this is a project that has been created in objective-c years before. 
I have found a solution: from objective-c call swift, which calls python.